# Using facet_wrap and ggsave in a figure with many panels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to generate scatter plots of two variables for several values of a third categorical variable (around 350). Here's my current code:

```
my.plot <- ggplot(aes(x=first_variable, y=second_variable, color=fourth_variable), data=my.data) + 
           geom_point() +
           facet_wrap(~ third_variable, scales = 'free')
ggsave(filename='test_plot.jpg', plot=my.plot, width=20, height=20, units='in', limitsize=FALSE)
```

However, the saved figure has font that is too big in relation to a plot area that is skewed and compressed. Is there a way I can shrink each panel's entire contents, font and all, to avoid overlapping and get good plots in the saved file?

These are two samples of the figure.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would save a larger figure and then rescale it in the viewer

Comment: Do you mean specifying a larger figure in ggsave with a larger width/height? The image is already quite big on my computer (20inx20in)...

Comment: I would make it as big as it needs to be to be legible, but if file size is a concern consider a better-suited file format such as svg or pdf, or, as last resort, lowering the resolution of a raster-based device such as png (jpg is a terrible choice for this type of graphic).

Comment: Thanks! Is my approach correct though? Or is there some other way you'd generate lots of subplots?

Comment: your approach seems fine, but it all depends on what you want to plot to convey. Sometimes when there are many panels, I find that axes can be removed altogether to focus more on the shape of the data. Strips are also quite space-hungry, so you could get rid off them and replace them with an annotation within the plot panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can try reducing the size of all of the text with something like `+ theme(text = element_text(size = 10))`, or look through the elements of [theme](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) to set text sizes for more specific elements.

Comment: This scales the font but is needing several iterations to get a usable figure. And the aspect ratio is also skewed. I'm looking for a more general fix...